# How do i pass an array from .cs file to .aspx

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

I have a webform called "Home.aspx".

In Home.aspx.cs, I created an array called myArray.

I want to use this array in Home.aspx to generate a word cloud.
something like below:

```
<script>
$('#wordcloud').jQCloud(myArray,{shape: 'rectangular'});
</script>
```

Can someone help me in solving this.

Comment: Could you please indicate what research you have done so far? This is rather basic question. Virtually all asp.net programs, many of which are open source have to do something similar to what you are asking.

Comment: Hi Andrew. I have searched in google for some time. And i asked this question as im new to .net(so didnt knew it was a very basic question) and  dont have much experience in .net coding.

Comment: In this case, I'd recommend you refer to your learning resources that you used for studying .net. It should be covered there very early on. Read about what  code behind in asp.net is and how it works. Reading up on OOP to understand what are classes, properties methods and relationship between them also will help. Finally, find out when and where different parts of your code are loaded and executed. Where your .net array is hosted, where your javascript runs and how information from server flows to the client. That should help.

Comment: thanks Andrew.. Will do that.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't want to put the C#-generated array onto your aspx page, because that array is a C# object, and javascript needs to be sent as text. You want to put a string output of the array onto the page. So you should create a string as a protected property in your code behind, and put the string of the array into *that*.

Then, on the front end, you can write the protected property onto the page with `<%= myString %>`

Comment: hi Jonathan.. thanks for the reply. can you please tell how to do that because im new to .net

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to achieve it.

1. Let server side code generate the whole JavaScript for you, which
   means you will need to construct the JS code as a string in the
   code-behind (.aspx.cs page) then use
   `ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` method to register it so
   that JS code will be executed when page loads.
2. Use server side script tag on your ASPX page. It's like point 1 but you write server side code on your front page.
3. Apply JS serialization and let the serialiser generate the JS array for you.

Below is an example of using a serialization approach.

```
<%
    // create you array here
    var myArray= new string[]{"apple", "orange"};
    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
%>
```

Then what you need is to place above code on your ASPX page, before your JavaScript code block.

```
<script>
    var myJsArray = <%= serializer.Serialize(myArray) %>;
    $('#wordcloud').jQCloud(myJsArray, {shape: 'rectangular'});
</script>
```

One thing to remember though, the server side array object and client side javascript array are two different things. The serialization/deserialization is required to allow data/array of data to be passed between browser and web server.